# hyperlink and bold word text display after form submission with innerhtml with javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, innerhtml

i display a block of text(based on user input) after form submission using innerHTML. i just wanted to know how to make a bold hyperlink within the text block. The text is displayed in a hidden panel below the form.
Many Thanks

Comment: With no code, of any kind, and only a vague 'description' of what you're doing – but, crucially, *no mention or explanation * of how you're doing it – we have no means by which to answer this question. Except with guesses. Please, take the time to show sufficient – though minimal – [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/MCVE) code to allow us to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understood you question, but...

you can use the old HTML tags `(like <b> or <i>)` directly into the `innerHTML = "";` without them being stripped.